# Can't figure out what network conditions have changed to cause network code to become non-functional

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

This is one of those situations where basically me leaving the building for 12 hours caused my code to stop working.

The code was being used in production/running for a few days to collect some data etc. for analysis. Now, the network portion of my code simply cannot function.

The code itself, where it is running, and the network it is on have NOT changed at all.

I've checked all the firewall rules on the server, and the clients. Nothing has changed there.

Now there's just an endless stream of my catch statements throwing miscellaneous network errors.

"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the host" - it wasn't

"Only one usage of each address is normally permitted" - there are no attempts made of this nature

The code I am using for the client/server is basically the code that was provided by Microsoft:

client: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

Comment: Are you closing/opening connections or keeping them open once established?

Comment: Same with the M$ example, the handles are shutdown then closed.

Comment: How quickly are you re-establishing or re-requesting data? Just because you close a socket, doesn't mean its available again (which can give the "only one usage of each address..." error). MS example code is there to demonstrate a concept, don't make the mistake of thinking its production code...

Comment: Not anywhere near fast or often enough for there to be any concurrency issues. We're talking about 1 client here sending a message every ~5 seconds. Also the software is quite literally running on a dedicated machine that has almost nothing except the OS and the server running.

Comment: I suspect that @RonBeyer is more concerned about running out of sockets because they are all stuck in TIME_WAIT, something that troubles periodic 'open/close' protocols, (which have piss-poor performance anyway 'cos open/close latency).  What does netstat say?

Comment: Yes, sockets when closed don't immediately become available again, and even waiting 5 seconds the system can try to reopen the same port that was just "closed" while in a wait state, which means that two sockets are trying to use the same address/protocol/port. You may need to set the `DontLinger` and `ReuseAddress` socket options on the underlying socket.

Comment: I will try those but the main issue here is nothing (no, really, ACTUALLY nothing) changed and the code simply stopped working, so I suspect anything I change in the CODE will have no effect.

Comment: IIRC, if it's the server that closes the connection, the associated server<>client socket is, by default, stuck in TIME_WAIT for 4 minutes.

Comment: Oh.. orite. So the problem is now 'permanent', ie. system has not recovered after restart. OK, so not TCP states, then:(

Comment: OK, are there other systems operating over the same network and, if so, are they showing any signs of 'stress'?  Is there any chance that some nice developer has plugged in a laptop, or other equipment, with a static IP address that clashes?

Comment: Have any strange, new bridges, routers or cables appeared?

Comment: No, to simplify things even further, the client and server are actually ON THEIR OWN router, they do not use static IPs but the router continuously leases the same IP to the devices in any case. There has been nothing new plugged into this router.

Comment: I mean.. if your system was working OK, and your server code, config etc has not changed, and you clients/configs have not changed, and you system has gone from 'always working' to 'never working', then it would seem that your network has morphed into a notwork and we really can't help with that here:(

Comment: What happens if you run a client, or some clients, and server on the same box over localhost?

Comment: Yeah.  Disconnect all the other cabled-up shit for yor test.

Comment: It appears to be working flawlessly over localhost. I even upped the message rate significantly (sending 5 per second sometimes) and I watched all the sends/receives come in and out just fine. The only thing that has been done to the server itself is perhaps the machine being rebooted at some point. And just to note, I didn't actually give localhost to the client, I gave it my local network address, though TCP might just figure out that its localhost anyway.

Comment: Certainly sounds like your network is shagged.  Maybe you could try the router again, but with only half the client boxes plugged in...

Comment: I'll try using a different machine as the server, as I'm suspecting it is something to do with the IIS install or firewall configuration on the original machine. Thanks for you help